# Fetch latest status for public Facebook page via PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a webpage where I want to simply display the latest status of a publicly available Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/jaycorvs).

I'm made an app, gotten the API key and secret key, etc... Using the PHP SDK I'm running into the following issue:

```
// Facebook
require_once('facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '5799359587XXXXX',
    'secret' => 'd466917a5XXXXXXXXXXXXX9dff4d77a79',
));

$status = $facebook->api("/jaycorvs/statuses?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken() );

// Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Requires user session thrown in /vhosts/asdfasdfa.com/public/facebook-php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1264
```

So, does this mean that, just to display a simple, publicly available status update on a webpage, I have to actually have the visitor go through the Facebook app permission process ("This page wants access to your friends, feed, etc")????

I'm looking at an old project I did a year ago and this was not the case then, as code is very similar from that project. Did Facebook change this lately?

Also, how come I can access the full feed (http://facebook.com/jaycorvs/feed) for the page but not just the statues by themselves with this app permission access? That doesn't make sense at all.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or does Facebook really require these type of app permissions for simply viewing a public status?

Answer (score 2):

Seems it’s a bug, has been reported in Feb 2013 already:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/480742545315442

But they have given this low priority, and not given any more updates as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also have another bug out regarding it, but in the meantime, there's a few ways around it:

First, parse the /feed, as you probably know, it's one way to get the data you want... I used to do this... but as the size of my data collections grew it became too process intensive...

The other option? Use /posts.

/posts... i *think* is analogous to /statuses, the main difference is in the format of the ID... ID in the /posts query is usually the pagename_nodeid

like [19292868552_10150189643478553](https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553)... you could splice that and reconstitute it to get posts...

if you search 10150189643478553 (hypothetically), you'll get the

```
{
  "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Requires user session", 
      "type": "OAuthException", 
      "code": 100
  }
}
```

but, adding the pageid as the prefix to the node id allows you to bypass the user session issue...

Comment: Note that /posts also includes the users comments on their posts.